# assignment supression and field width in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

in printf a field width may be specified as '*'

```
printf("%*s", 99, str);
```

how can i do the same in scanf without it being interpreted as an assignment suppression character ?

Example1:

```
char str[100];
scanf("%**s %s", 10, str);
```

the 1st asterisk should be interpreted as assignment supression and the 2nd as the field width, thus the above scanf should read and ignore 10 characters, and then read and store the next string in str.

Example2:

```
char str[100];
scanf("%*s", 10, str);
```

the 1st asterisk should be interpreted as the field width, so the above scanf should read 10 characters and store them in str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this.  `scanf` doesn't work in the same way as `printf`.  Specifically:

- an asterisk in the format string always means 'suppress the assignment'
- field widths must appear as literals in the format string; they cannot appear as parameters of `scanf`

Full documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: My disappointment is immeasurable, and my day is ruined

Comment: @OsourceAll Join the club. (The only salvation is that getting the field width just right is kind of a sophisticated thing to do, and `scanf` is really only useful in relatively unsophisticated programs.  If you're ready to get the field widths just right, hopefully you're ready to move on to something better than `scanf` for input.)

Comment: You could construct your format string on the fly (using `sprintf`, perhaps).  It doesn't have to be a string literal.

Comment: yeah, i think i gonna have to use sprintf, thanks